# Using CTA Buttons as Supplemental Subnav

Tags: navigation, menu

I am a content administrator for a major US city that's using Craft CMS. The content categories for our website (i.e., Resources, Services, Topics, etc.) are great for providing different ways to input and display information. But they also serve as a left-hand side navigation set on pages that have content in each of those categories. The problem is that these content categories provide very little context for visitors regarding the topics for those Resources, Services, and so forth.

To help alleviate this problem, I am seeking to create a supplemental subnavigation menu that allows people to go to landing pages that provide more context for visitors seeking different types of information or services (see attached mock-up). I really like how CTA buttons appear toward the top of index pages, and think they could serve as quick and accessible ways of linking people to subpages on our department's website.

Is there a way to customize the Craft CMS to allow for multiple CTA buttons on select landing pages (perhaps up to 8 buttons total)? Or are there more elegant ways to create a useful supplemental sub-nav menu?

Thanks in advance for any advice folks may have on this!

[image: Draft sub-navigation mockup using CTA buttons.]

Comment: Yes, all of these things can be done with Craft CMS. But you'd need some development work done in the templates.

Comment: Yes. But it's not a good design approach.

Comment: Thanks Platopus. I appreciate the candor. I'm a little concerned about the design aspect as well. My thought was that at least the buttons would show up higher on the page, especially for folks using mobile devices, thus enabling ready use of the supplemental nav. Any suggestions on an improved approach?

Comment: Hi @AaronLehmer-Chang... The answer is YES, this can be created in your CraftCMS website... Unfortunately, the HOW is much more complicated since every CraftCMS project is uniquely coded/setup by the developer who built the site. Most likely this is something that would need to be added to your project for you by a CraftCMS developer/programmer.